# Can't choose "select" element via VBA DOM controls

Tags: vba, dom, excel, web-scraping

I'm trying to automatically process a form via Excel VBA. On the website I'm currently working with, I'm able to click buttons and fill in text fields without any issues. However, there's one "select" box that I can't work with: 1stNav. Normally, I'd do something like `Document.getElementById("1stNav").Options(1).Selected = True`, but I can't get the object.

I've tried using `.getElementById("1stNav"), .getElementsByName("1stNav"), .all.Item("1stNav").` Nothing seems to work. I can use these functions to select other DOM objects. What gives? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here's the source code (screen-shot so it's easier to read):

[image: HTML source code]

The full tag is: `&lt;select name="lstNav" class="ListNav" id="lstNav" style="background-color: whitesmoke;" onmouseover="this.className='ListNavExpand';" onmouseout="this.className='ListNav';" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'lstNav\',\'\')', 0)" size="4"&gt;`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like the HTML code has "lstNav" (with a lower-case "L") and your VBA code has "1stNav" (with a number 1).  Could that be the issue?

Comment: Darn! So obvious! Thank you.

Comment: :-) Happens to all of us!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I rarely look at comments to find an answer, I'll add it in down here as well:

It looks like the HTML code has "lstNav" (with a lower-case "L") and the VBA code has "1stNav" (with a number 1).